# Expiration for a single MongoDB document doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'd like to have a specific expiration time for each document in my collection. I've been following this [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586358/10255450) (but in Python).

This is how I'm creating an index:

```
self.coll.create_index([('expireAt', 1)], expireAfterSeconds=0)
```

This is the document I'm saving to Mongo

```
document = {'_id': key, 'value': value, 'expireAt': expire_at}
self.coll.replace_one({'_id': key}, document, upsert=True)
```

I do see the index was created but I can also see expired documents that should have been deleted.

Why?

**EDIT:** Is it possible that it's since the collection is `capped`?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

- Check the collection isn't capped
- use `datetime.utcnow()` and not `datetime.now()`